# Trying to do a single Discord.js command without a prefix

Tags: discord.js

I am attempting to make a command like dank memer has, when someone says F or f, the bot replies with F. My problem is that it will not work without the prefix, but I would like to be able to do it without the prefix.
Here is my code. I use a command handler.

```
//THIS IS THE INDEX.JS FILE 

const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { default_prefix, token_bot } = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');



client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./Commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
    
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready Player One!'); 
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(default_prefix) || message.author.bot) return; 

    const args = message.content.slice(default_prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 
    
    if (command === 'f'){
        client.commands.get('f').execute(message, args);
    }
```

And this one is the f.js command that it calls on.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'f',
    description: "This is an f command",
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send('F');
       
    },
};
```

This is not all of my index.js file, it is too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is very simple. All commands have prefixes, so I would not consider what you are trying to create as a command, I would say it is technically more of an auto-response. Therefore, you should not be using the code of your `args` or `command` variables to check if "F" has been sent, you should instead directly check the message's content.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(default_prefix) || message.author.bot) return; 

    const args = message.content.slice(default_prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/); 
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase(); 

    if (message.content.toLowerCase() == 'f'){
        client.commands.get('f').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

I would advise looking into the `args` and `command` variables and learning how their values are being retrieved. Your code, as it is, seems to heavily rely on a simple template, but you cannot entirely depend on this template if you want to fully customize how your bot/commands will look and function.